# Метод Rollback EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, шаблоны-проектирования

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать `Rollback` используя `EntityFramework 6.x`, а так же паттерн Unit of work. Для этого имеется класс интерфейс `IUnitOfWork`

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
   void Commit();
   // void Rollback();
}
```

и класс - `UnitOfWork`

```
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork 
    {
        public DbContext Context { get; private set; }

        public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }

        public void Commit()
        {            
            if (Context != null)
            {
                Context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (Context != null)
            {
                Context.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Знаю что на уровне T-SQL это задается таким образом:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  // операции взаимодействия
  IF (@@error <> 0)
        ROLLBACK
COMMIT
```

**UPD**

Планируется использоваться так

```
try
{
    repository.Delete(...);
    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
catch
{
   unitOfWork.Rollback();
   // регистрация ошибки
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто вызовите Dispose не вызывая Commit. Или вручную в finally, или с использованием using:

```
using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(context))
{
    repository.Delete(...);
    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
catch
{
   // регистрация ошибки
}
```

Если ошибка произойдет до вызова SaveChanges - изменения будут просто выброшены Dispose-ом обертки и контекста.

Если ошибка произойдет в процессе выполнения SaveChanges - то будет откачена транзакция SQL, которую EF открывает в начале SaveChanges и коммитает после сохранения всех изменений.

Только не забывайте, что на самом деле контекст в EF - это и есть готовая реализация паттернов Unit Of Work + Repository. А ваш UnitOfWork - это просто прокси-обертка, которая сама по себе UoW не реализует - она просто отделяет интерфейс UoW от репозитория.

Поэтому контекст у вас должен живет у вас не дольше обертки, так что вы не сможете (и не должны) использовать его повторно для другого экземпляра UnitOfWork.

Comment: Можете пояснить последний абзац?

Comment: А если не будет ошибки и необходимо отменить транзакцию? Уже по логам смотреть ?

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk ваша обертка при вызове Dispose разрушает тот контекст, который был в нее передан. Т.е. вы не можете создать uow1 поверх какого-то context1, разрушить uow1, а потом создать uow2 поверх того же context1  - упадет.

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk если вызван Commit/SaveChanges - то транзакцию откатить нельзя. Т.к. транзакции в SQL Server - Durable, их нельзя "раскоммитать". Если SaveChanges вызван не был - просто не вызываете его, и все изменения просто выбрасываются.

Answer (score 3):

Аналогичный вопрос задавал пользователь на английском StackOverflow: [How to rollback a transaction in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070040/how-to-rollback-a-transaction-in-entity-framework). Проведя эксперимент, он выяснил что в случае ошибки которая возникает при вызове метода DbContext.SaveChanges, Entity Framework автоматически откатывает все изменения.